# EF warning - If the configured precision and scale don't match the column type in the database, this will cause values to be silently truncated

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6

Recently we've migrated one of our project from ADO.net to EntityFramework 7. In the log file we've noticed multiple warnings like the following,

> The decimal property 'ObjectId' is part of a key on entity type
> 'AppointmentSchedule'. If the configured precision and scale don't
> match the column type in the database, this will cause values to be
> silently truncated if they do not fit in the default precision and
> scale. Consider using a different property as the key, or make sure
> that the database column type matches the model configuration and
> enable decimal rounding warnings using 'SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT ON'

Did some research and as recommended in forums, tried the following approaches

tried setting,

1. .HasColumnType("numeric(9, 0)");
2. .HasPrecision("numeric(9, 0)")

Also tried settings the data annotation on the EF model property

```
[Column(TypeName = "numeric(9, 0)")] 
public decimal ObjectId { get; set; }
```

None of the above has helped. we are still seeing the warnings. Any suggestion how to avoid those warnings?

Comment: have you tried `.Property(e => e.ObjectId).HasPrecision(9, 0);`?

Comment: @viveknuna Yes, tried it as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One solution is to use `DbContextOptionsBuilder.ConfigureWarnings`. Check answer from this GitHub [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/29912) and Microsoft [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontextoptionsbuilder.configurewarnings?view=efcore-7.0)

```
var contextOptions = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext>()
    .ConfigureWarnings(w => w.Ignore(SqlServerEventId.DecimalTypeKeyWarning))
    .UseSqlServer(@"...connectionString")
    .Options;

using var context = new MyDbContext(contextOptions);
```

Comment: I think this is the ideal option to remove warnings without changing EF model property type from decimal to int. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You have a `decimal` type property and a trying to store it's data in a SQL numeric type with 9 digits and 0 decimal places. This means that it will not be possible to store anything after the decimal point. The problem is that `ObjectId` should probably be an `int` not a `decimal`.

Also since the max int size is 2147483647, you should make the SQl type allow 10 digits:

```
[Column(TypeName = "numeric(10, 0)")]
```

Comment: Warning disappeared after setting the EF model property type from decimal to int. Thanks

Comment: I don't believe converting EF model property from decimal to int is the correct solution. I see SQL numeric is mapped to decimal. In the numeric DB field with numeric(10,0) you can store values > max int. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-data-type-mappings

Comment: Yes, you can store greater values than max int with numeric(10, 0) but you cannot store the max int with numeric(9, 0). Since the values written to the DB will be driven by the code, we don't need to worry that something greater than max int could fit in the DB. We just need to ensure that max int can be written to the DB.